# Vue with vuex mapState change type int to string when v-model apply?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use mapState  from 'vuex'. My state object `init` has several properties, among them 'init.min' (which is the number). When I bind it with `v-model` in `input type="text"` it also remains a number. But when the user makes any change in form input `init.min` data converted to string. I tried to change `<input type="number"/>` but it doesn't work. Why is the number that comes from mapState and is attached to the form input with `v-model`, when changed, it is converted to a string and spoils my validation. Vuelidate expects a number and there is a string.

```
  computed:{
 
    ...mapState({
    init: 'init'
    })
   
},
```

in component template

```
    <input v-model="init.min" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `v-model.number`? https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number

```
<input v-model.number="init.min" type="number" />
```

Copy from the docs:

> If you want user input to be automatically typecast as a Number, you can add the `number` modifier to your `v-model` managed inputs:
>
> `<input v-model.number="age" type="number">`
>
> This is often useful, because even with `type="number"`, the value of HTML input elements always returns a string. If the value cannot be parsed with `parseFloat()`, then the original value is returned.